# any third party free Java library that can calculate grades based upon marks of student?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi i am making a school information software. Is there any third party reliable library that can be used for calculating grades of students referring marks for the same from specified database.It should be flexible enough to let client specify criteria for grade calculation in terms of standard deviation, median etc.

Comment: We had a project in one of our semesters for a similar thing. You can find it at https://projects.fslab.de/projects/AbschlussnotenRechner - Docs are mostly german, but maybe it helps.

Comment: This honestly would be easier to do yourself. Grading is really just weighted averages, maybe class statistics, right? Those are easy to implement yourself (esp. in Java). You'd be better off with that than some library in German (and god knows how they grade there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using a rules engine such as Drools, JESS or JRules. Then you would be able to dynamically change the rules without having to change your source code

Comment: No i didn't thought about it till now for Grading component. But if its works it will be great. Specially it may help me to generate another component "rule based alerts engine"? Can u please refer me some good articles for that same so that i can avoid wrong end.

Thanks

Comment: http://legacy.drools.codehaus.org/Why+Use+Rules

http://blog.athico.com/

http://ctat.pact.cs.cmu.edu/docs/ctat_2_1/writing_jess_rules.html

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2006/jw-1107-brms.html